# Whan calculating the significance of a difference, when do we use separate variances and when do we use pooled variance?

Tags: variance, differences

When you check if the difference between two sample proportions is significant, some sources ([like Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/two-sample-inference/two-sample-z-test-proportions/v/hypothesis-test-for-difference-in-proportions-example)) recommend using a pooled variance, while others ([for instance statistics for dummies](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-estimate-the-difference-between-two-proportions/)) recommend simply adding the separate variances of the two different sample proportions together.

When is it optimal to use the first solution and when (if ever) is it optimal to use the second one?

Comment: The first link seems to be a hypothesis test where the null hypothesis is that the two samples are drawn from distributions with the same proportions of successes, while the second link seems to be constructing a confidence interval for the difference between the two proportions.

Comment: Yes sure but the confidence interval is the mirror image of the hypotheis test in my opinion and the variances are constructed in the same way, I can find some other site recommending the second solution if it helps.

Comment: Apparently, Penn state university recommends using pooled variance to perform test on the null hypothesis and separata variances to prove if the difference is equal to some other specific value, is there some credit to this argument?

Comment: The two versions of the test give almost the same results when sample sizes are equal. Respectable web sites and textbooks use each method. My Answer mentions a few differences between the pooled and separate variances tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minitab software gives the option to do the test either with
a variance based on a pooled estimate of the hypothetical common proportion or with a variance based on separate estimates of the proportions. (Both tests use normal approximations, so neither should be used for very small sample sizes.)

Because the null hypothesis assumes proportions are equal and the test
is based on the null distribution, there may be a theoretical
argument for the pooling. The account of this test given by
[NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) shows a formula for the pooled variance. The procedure `prop.test` in R gives results that agree with Minitab's pooled method (see the note).

When sample sizes are equal, there is little difference between P-values from the two
methods. But when samples sizes are different, as for the data used below, there can be a noticeable
difference between the two P-values.

[Minitab shows results from Fisher's exact test with both methods; this test does not use an estimated variance, so both of its printouts show the same
P-value for Fisher's test. (Fisher's test can be used for small samples.)]

**Pooled.** Significant at the 1% level for the data shown.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       21  200  0.105000
2       19  400  0.047500

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0575
95% CI for difference:  (0.0101765, 0.104823)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = 2.66  P-Value = 0.008

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.014
```

**Separate.** Results are similar to those for the pooled test for the same data, but not significant at the 1% level.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       21  200  0.105000
2       19  400  0.047500


Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0575
95% CI for difference:  (0.0101765, 0.104823)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
  Z = 2.38  P-Value = 0.017

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.014
```

*Notes:* (1) The similar `prop.test` in R (without continuity correction)
gives a P-value that agrees with the pooled method. This test uses
a chi-squared statistic $7.0848; \sqrt{7.0848} = 2.6617.$

```
prop.test(c(21,19), c(200,400), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
              without continuity correction

data:  c(21, 19) out of c(200, 400)
X-squared = 7.0848, df = 1, p-value = 0.007774
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01017653 0.10482347
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
0.1050 0.0475
```

(2) However, notice that 95% CIs for all three printouts agree, using a separate
variances estimate for the standard error
$\hat \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n_1} + \frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n_2}}.$ So, if you want a CI that 'inverts the test', then you should
use the separate variances test.